# how to delete a row in a table acording to a value coming from another form in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to delete a row in my FormClosing event of mainFrm form the value of where condition that deletes the row is coming from another form which is contained by a textBox
the codes of first form which has to transform the value to the next form are

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(userNametxt.Text); 
 MainFrm mainfrm = new MainFrm(id);
 mainfrm.Show();
 this.Hide();
```

The codes for the constructor of the second form are:

```
public MainFrm(int id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            deleteById = id;
        }
```

The codes of FormClosing event in the second form are:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete empId,empPerm from empLogin where empId="+deleteById+"", cn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cn.Close();
```

The id variable is declared above the constructor ... the exception is "incorrect syntax near',' "any help !!

Comment: possibly, your delete statement is incorrect. `DELETE FROM empLogin WHERE empId=" + deleteById`

Comment: @Tima'a - please avoid concatenating strings to add the parameters. This is susceptible for SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: @GiladGreen can you give me an example on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a row by using this code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete empId,empPerm from empLogin where empId="+deleteById+"", cn);
```

Instead of using this code, you can use this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId="+deleteById+"", cn);
```

If you want to delete a data from that column,you should use update query like this:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update empLogin set empPerm='' where empId="+deleteById+"", cn);
```

Comment: @Subash - please avoid concatenating strings to add the parameters. This is susceptible for SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: Thank you for your suggesstion, Mr.Gilad Green.

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly said that `Incorrect syntax near ','`

Your delete statement is incorrect. Correct delete statement is:

```
DELETE FROM empLogin WHERE empId=" + deleteById
```

Comment: the same exception appear

Comment: replace your code as: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId="+deleteById+"", cn);` It should works.